# global scss variable with @import at top

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible? I've using scss with react and I've to create many .scss files, what's annyoing is that I always have to `@import` variable although it's global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a entry point scss file name **"app.scss"**
Then create **"_variables.scss"** file which will contain all variables.

Then you create other component files like **"_header.scss, _button.scss" ...**

Then import the _variables.scss file in app.scss.

*app.scss*

```
@import "variables.scss" /*Note that this should be before any other components*/
@import "header"
@import "button"
...
```

> Importing it at the top will ensure that all remainig components will
>   have acess to the variables

Then import the app.sccs file in your reactjs app.

Comment: if there is a new file in my components/button/button.scss, without importing variable.scss I can use the variable? why?

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan Because the sass compiler will find out  that the variables have already been imported on top, before buttons

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan ,In the end, everything should be imported in app.scss

Comment: Note that you can omit the '.scss' extension in these imports.

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan , if this answer helped you then please accept it